# how to handle a multi row form without a binding object in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I don't know to structure my question perfectly, but Im trying to get data from a html multiple row form and I dont want to use a binding objects and I dont want to have to many `@RequestParam` parameters on my request handling method. I want the form submission to return an array of int, but i get the following error `HTTP Status 400 - Required int[] parameter 'department' is not present`. I tried writing the form the same way one would do in php like this:

```
<form action="processForm" method="POST">
<select name="department[]">
    <option value="NONE">---SELECT---</option>
    <c:forEach items="${departments}" var="department">
    <option value="${department.getId()}">${department.getName()}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
<select name="department[]">
    <option value="NONE">---SELECT---</option>
    <c:forEach items="${departments}" var="department">
    <option value="${department.getId()}">${department.getName()}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
<select name="department[]">
    <option value="NONE">---SELECT---</option>
    <c:forEach items="${departments}" var="department">
    <option value="${department.getId()}">${department.getName()}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
<select name="department[]">
    <option value="NONE">---SELECT---</option>
    <c:forEach items="${departments}" var="department">
    <option value="${department.getId()}">${department.getName()}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
</form>
```

my controller request mapping methods are as follows

```
@Request(value = "/form",nethod = RequestMethod.GET)
public String renderForm(){
    return "form"
}

@Request(value = "processForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@RequestParam("department") int [] department){
    for (int i=0;i<department.lenth;i++){
        System.out.println(department[i]);
    }
}
```

thanks you in advance.

Comment: Is the form always fixed with 4 selects?

Comment: No Im gonna add javascript to allow the user to add as many rows as they require

Comment: if you just have one or few variables to get just use getParameterValues, it's more simple and it can't be wrong int [] department = request.getParameterValues("department") and remember to remove [] from your html so name="department"

Comment: Thanks a billion Ive been trying to figure this out for so long. Im new to Java EE and Spring but Im coming along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `@RequestParam` to `@RequestParam("department[]")`

```
@Request(value = "processForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@RequestParam("department[]") int [] department){
    for (int i=0;i<department.lenth;i++){
        System.out.println(department[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works as well as the solution @ah-shianghan gave me in the comments

Comment: @Piet Glad I could help.  I noticed his solution in the comments, but I setup an example on my local machine and figured might as well post.